# Download JSEclipse plugin stand-alone

Tags: javascript, eclipse, ide

Is there anywhere I can download the stand-alone JSEclipse plugin, it seems like it only comes bundled with the trial edition FlexBuilder plugins.

It used to be available here:
http://www.interaktonline.com/products/eclipse/jseclipse/overview/

I still find it useful to use but I'd rather not have the cruft of an expired Flex builder trial license in my Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the plugin jar from [here](http://download.macromedia.com/pub/labs/jseclipse/autoinstall/features/com.interaktonline.jseclipse_1.5.5.jar).

Or you can add the [update site](http://download.macromedia.com/pub/labs/jseclipse/autoinstall/site.xml) on Eclipse.

Comment: Both links are dead :-(

Answer (score 2):

It's not available anymore in the Adobe site, but I have it zipped, and uploaded the plugin to filefactory. Here's the link: [JSeclipse](http://www.filefactory.com/file/1e1raui4ocmn/n/jsEclipse_zip). The zip has 2 folders: features and plugins. Unzip the folders into the corresponding folder in your eclipse and enjoy. I tested it in both Ganymede and Juno and it works in both.

Answer (score 0):

The answer given is for version 1.5 but the current version of JSEclipse is above 1.8

Does this mean that the correct answer is no? You can't get JSEclipse without FlexBuilder?